# Cannot find module '@uirouter/core' on Angular 8 project with UIRouter

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

When I create a new angular project with angular-cli, after installing the UIRotuer package through `npm install @uirouter/angular` and importing the module into the `app.module.ts` imports array, I get the error I show in the photo .

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR3K4.jpg

```
ERROR in node_modules/@uirouter/angular/directives/uiSref.d.ts:3:63 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

3 import { UIRouter, Obj, TransitionOptions, TargetState } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/directives/uiSrefStatus.d.ts:5:46 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

5 import { TargetState, UIRouterGlobals } from '@uirouter/core';
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/directives/uiView.d.ts:4:69 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

4 import { StateDeclaration, UIRouter, ViewConfig, ViewContext } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/index.d.ts:10:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

10 export * from '@uirouter/core';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/interface.d.ts:3:76 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

3 import { StateDeclaration, _ViewDeclaration, Transition, HookResult } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/lazyLoad/lazyLoadNgModule.d.ts:4:62 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

4 import { Transition, LazyLoadResult, StateDeclaration } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~m
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/providers.d.ts:89:129 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

89 import { UIRouter, StateRegistry, StateService, TransitionService, UrlMatcherFactory, UrlRouter, ViewService, UrlService } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                                                                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/statebuilders/lazyLoad.d.ts:3:62 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

3 import { LazyLoadResult, Transition, StateDeclaration } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/statebuilders/lazyLoad.d.ts:4:46 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

4 import { BuilderFunction, StateObject } from '@uirouter/core';
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/statebuilders/views.d.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

2 import { StateObject } from '@uirouter/core';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/statebuilders/views.d.ts:3:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

3 import { PathNode } from '@uirouter/core';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/statebuilders/views.d.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

4 import { ViewConfig } from '@uirouter/core';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/uiRouterConfig.d.ts:2:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

2 import { UIRouter, StateObject } from '@uirouter/core';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@uirouter/angular/uiRouterNgModule.d.ts:6:92 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@uirouter/core'.

6 import { UrlRuleHandlerFn, TargetState, TargetStateDef, UIRouter, TransitionService } from '@uirouter/core';
                                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4300, open your browser on http://localhost:4300/ **
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I suppose the problem is with ui-router, because until I impored the module the console didn't give errors.
I tried to reinstall the dependencies but it continues to give me that problem that up until a few days ago didn't give me.

Comment: We run Angularjs and Angular as hybrid and I had an issue with AngularJS '@uirouter/angularjs' module in this case. Downgrading it from 1.1.0 to 1.0.30 helped.

Answer (score 2):

I run into same problem. Installing missing packages solved it for me.

```
npm install @uirouter/core
npm install @uirouter/rx
```